# Access denied SSIS w/ Parameters via xp_cmdshell

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, xp-cmdshell

I have searched up and down for a solution and cannot find anything that helps.  Everything that I have tried doesnt seem to work.

I have two database.  I cannot modify Database A by adding a table or anything like that.  I cannot enable cross-database access.  I believe I cant use sp.Start_job because I need to pass parameters.  I was able to enable xp_cmdshell.

**My Database Definition:**

```
Database A 
    - Order table 
Database B 
    - Email notification Table
```

**What I need to do:**

```
Any time an order is entered into Database A, I need to enter a row into Database B with values of the order. So I need to have parameters
```

**What I have tried:**

```
- xp_cmdshell @query='DTEXEC /f "\\Server\Folder\SSIS Packages\Order confirmations\Order confirmations\Package.dtsx" /DECRYPT password'
   1. I get an error saying access denied.  I tried setting up sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account (##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account##) to an account that has access to the network drive where the file is stored, no luck.
   2. whoami.exe shows NT/Authority \System instead of my proxy account.
   3. GRANT EXECUTE on xp_cmdshell to [mydomain\myAccount] didnt have any affect.
```

[Whoami Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw2t1.jpg)

[xp_cmdshell Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWPsR.jpg)

Any suggestions?  The job runs fine if I set it up with SQL Server  Agent.  Eventually I will just call xp_cmdshell from a trigger on Database A table Orders to enter the data into Database B and then fire off an email with sp_send_dbmail if some conditions are met.

Comment: If you can't modify A, how are you going to implement a trigger in it?

Comment: Sorry, all I can add is a trigger.  I was more talking about the structure of adding a table or adding columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I could currently find (Without resturcturing permissions in SQL and the network was to give read/execute permission to SQL server.  Not my ideal solution, but it works.

Hope this helps someone